useSound dynamic volume in NextJS
I am trying to implement a global volume button that sets volume level for button click, I'm using https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound.
I have this VolumeButton.tsx
export default function VolumeButton() {
    const { context, dispatch } = useContext(MyContext);
    const [volumeLevel, setVolumeLevel] = useState(appState.volume);

    const handleClick = () => {
        const newLevel =
            (volumeLevel + 25) % 125 < 75 ? (volumeLevel + 25) % 125 : 100;
        setVolumeLevel(newLevel);
        dispatch({ type: 'setVolume', payload: newLevel });
    };

    const getVolumeIcon = () => {
        if (volumeLevel === 0) return IoVolumeMute;
        if (volumeLevel === 25) return IoVolumeLow;
        if (volumeLevel === 50) return IoVolumeMedium;
        return IoVolumeHigh;
    };

    const VolumeIcon = getVolumeIcon();

    return (
        <Tooltip label={`Volume: ${volumeLevel}%`} placement="top">
            <IconButton
                aria-label={`Volume: ${volumeLevel}%`}
                icon={<VolumeIcon />}
                onClick={handleClick}
                variant="white"
                colorScheme="white"
                zIndex={3}
                size="md"
            />
        </Tooltip>
    );
}

Then I'm using it as such in index.tsx:
const Footer = () => {
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
    const { context} = useContext(MyContext);
    const [showRaise, setShowRaise] = useState<boolean>(false);

    let [playCircle] = useSound('/sound/circle.mp3', {
        volume: context.volume,
        interrupt: true,
    });
    let [playSquare] = useSound('/sound/square.mp3', {
        volume: context.volume,
        interrupt: true,
    });
    let [playRectangle] = useSound('/sound/rectangle.mp3', {
        volume: context.volume,
        interrupt: true,
    });

    const handleClick1 = () => {
         playCircle();
    };

    const handleClick2 = () => {
         playSquare();
    };

    const handleClick3 = () => {
         playRectangle();
    };

.....

<Button onClick={() => handleClick1()} />
<Button onClick={() => handleClick2()} />
<Button onClick={() => handleClick3()} />


But the volume seems to be not consistent, there are times where it remains muted even though I set volume to 100.
